SEO - Images appearing on Google results
When I search Google with site:subdomain.example.com" keyword1 keyword2 keyword3", it shows only one image as a preview. However, a specific page on the same site, like https://subdomain.example.com/keyword1-keyword2-keyword3/, shows three preview images for the same query. Why does this happen?
I have more than 3000 products & pics on my site, and all products have been imported with the same method. So, for all pics, pic name has been generated to include keywords, I have set alt text, title, caption, and description. I also can see all images are indexed on Google images, so this seems not to be a indexation issue.
Why is the result aleatory? What should I do to fix it?

It shows me more.  Try flushing your browser first.

I tried in a private navigation, or with other browser, and same result... only 1 pic ...

I see a lot of images too. This question is quite unclear.

Without more information or some HTML, it is hard to give advice. Can you revise your question to include some more information?
